# How to create a circuit to reduce my H-Bridge Inputs from 4 to 2, much like the 4427 Dual Driver does?

Tags: microcontroller, h-bridge, input

My H-bridge is identical to the one here:
http://www.robotroom.com/BipolarHBridge2.html

I'm trying to reduce the number of inputs from 4-2 so I can control it with my arduino using the 2 inputs.

In his book, the creator of that website mentions using the IC1 4427 Dual Driver (non-inverting)

Why not just use 2 transitors, one which activates both R1/R4 and R2/R3? (forward, reverse, 2 inputs)  I'm assuming it has something to do with applying the exact equal power to both transistor bases?

If that is the case, how would I manually create a circuit that accomplishes what the 4427 dual driver does?

[image: 4427]

What I'm really curious about: what are the advantages to using a 4424 Dual Driver to turn on the 2 inputs at a time as opposed to 2 more transistors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say your H bridge is identical to the one on the link but it doesn't specifically give values for the transistors and diodes - it gives options and ideas so we are missing information about what you actually have. Yes, you can do what you have proposed, the 4 inputs can become 2 inputs. This will give you: -

1. Off
2. Forward
3. Reverse

And if you do some messing with the logic it can give you fast braking where both top (or bottom) transistors are on with the intention of stopping the motor quickly (rather than just letting it free-wheel.

If you are really careful with the design you could use PWM control and get really good energy efficiencies. Especially useful if all you have as a power source is a battery.

Having said all of that, the kudos of building a H-bridge is somewhere between succesfully going to the toilet and shuffling playing cards without dropping any so, why not buy one that does the job. I'm thinking [DRV8837](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8837.pdf) or take a look at TI's portfolio (it includes the 8837) [here](http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/amplifiers-linear/brushed-dc-driver-products.page#p2127=65;1250): -

[image]

I've drawn a red block around the most important parameters to consider i.e. operating voltage and motor currents. I meant to add, don't consider either of the following for a low voltage H bridge if you might be taking about an amp: -

- L293
- L298
- SN754410

They just don't cut the mustard these days.

Comment: Thx for the great answer! What are the advantages to using a 4424 Dual Driver to turn on the 2 inputs at a time as opposed to 2 more transistors?

Comment: I'd need a circuit with values, motor current and supply voltage ideally. You could use transistors or the driver for sure.

Answer (score 1):

When you examine the driver schematic, I see a Totem Pole complementary driver which is low impedance for both hi/lo voltage source. This gives fast turn off times and the high side has extra filters for commutation dead-time in fullbridge mode.

A low side driver will cause the motor to coast with inertia when shutoff.  A dual hi/lo driver with deadband will it stop instantly with brakes.  Both methods have different drivers and  require only 2 lines and ground but have different stop responses, which are up to you.  The Rds of the switch must be << than the motor coil resistance.